# Traduções de tooltips de flags em comentários e respostas aceitas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Em uma pergunta com resposta aceita, ao passar o mouse em cima do "vezinho verde", esta tooltip aparece:

> *The question owner accepted this as the best answer DD/MM às HH:mm.*
>   [image]

O curioso é o "às" ali no meio, mas o resto está em inglês.

Ao passar o mouse em cima da banderinha em um comentário, esta tooltip aparece:

> *Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention*
>   [image]